# Jquery children i-й элемент

Tags: jquery

Есть такой код. Работает, но я хочу избавиться от `cls = '.reviews__text-review_' + i;` Как с помощью `.children()` получить конкретный по счету элемент?
Я находил так: `$('.reviews__text-container').children()[i];` Но не получается применить к такому элементу функции Jquery. Как найти i-й по счету элементы или как `$('.reviews__text-container').children()[i];` сделать, чтобы работали функции JQuery?

```
// Следующий, предыдущий отзыв
$('.reviews__control .arrow-left').click(function () {
    var i = 0;
    var cls = 0;
    var children = $('.reviews__text-container').children();
    children.each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')){
            $(this).hide();
            if (i-1 >= 0){
                cls = '.reviews__text-review_' + i;
                $(cls).show();
                return false;
            }else {
                cls = '.reviews__text-review_' + (children.length);
                $(cls).show();
                return false;
            }
        }
        i++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
$('.reviews__text-container').children().eq(i);
```

Этот код вернет объект джейквери, который содержит соответствующие методы.

Comment: Спасибо! То что искал!